# Specific Garamond font for LaTeX

Tags: fonts, garamond

On MC Word I’ve got a version of Garamond font that looks like this:

[image]

It looks different compared to `urw-garamond` as well as to other Garamond fonts I know so far (like EB Garamond, Cormorant Garamond or garamondx). The most catchy spots are for example the twirly "z" (if you look for *Französisch* above) or some capital letters that are not as inclined as the following small letters (see for example the "F" in *Französisch* or the "T" in *The*) in italic. None of the Garamond fonts I know have these traits.

Do you know the Garamond font version I’m talking about?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: you  can use pdffonts utility or your pdf reader (certainly acrobat reader) font menu to check what fonts are in a pdf document

Comment: I just looked in Word and it seems to look like the one I have that simply has the font name Garamond so you could use the  same name font with xelatex or lualatex. (it is from Monotype but a standard Windpws font I think)

Comment: Thank you, I’ve done some further research, Monotype Garamond is exactly the font I need. Unfortunately, it doesn’t exist in the font catalogue … yet I haven’t figured out a way to get the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any system font with lualatex or xelatex.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond}

\begin{document}

One two three  \textit{The} and \textit{Französisch}

\end{document}
```